# XML Schema: Why can't <xs:all> have <choice> children? and how can this be bypassed?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create a schema for a `<property>` element which must have a `<key>` sub-element, and one of `<val>`, `<shell>` or `<perl>` and an optional `<os>` or `<condition>`, and the order of the sub-elements doesn't matter.

Here are some sample for valid `<property>` elements:

```
<property>
  <key>A</key>
  <val>b</val>
</property>

<property>
  <key>A</key>
  <val>b</val>
  <os>Windows</os>
</property>

<property>
  <condition>a == 1</condition>
  <key>A</key>
  <perl>1+1</perl>
  <os>unix</os>
</property>
```

Ideally, I thought of using `<xs:all>` for this:

```
<xs:element name="property">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="val" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="perl" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="shell" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="os" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      <xs:element name="condition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But I found out that `<xs:all>` can contain only `<xs:element>` and not `<xs:choice>`. Can someone explain why is it?

More importantly, can someone provide a way to validate such a `<property>` element?

I can put the three elements - `<val>`, `<perl>` and `<shell>` - as optional elements in the `<xs:all>`, but I want the schema to validate that one and only one of the three exists in the element. Can this be done?

Comment: @splintor: Have you actually looked at the preview window when writing your question? I mean, half of it was invisible...

Comment: Do you mean that both os and condition can occur within the same property element or that one or the other or neither can occurr?

Comment: @Tomalak: No - I missed that preview window. Thanks a lot for editing it to mean what I wanted.

Comment: @newt: I mean os and condition can occur within the same property element, or only one of them or neither. Both of them are opitonal, and they are not mutual exclusive.

Comment: @splintor: OK. Just checking. I have a feeling that your need for lack of ordering may make this very hard to express in xsd. It might be solveable using substitution groups but I'm not sure.

Comment: @newt: Thanks, this is what I was afraid of. Do you have any idea why it is like that? Whay can't a xs:all element contain xs:choice?

Comment: Implementation of schema processors will be a factor (as <all> doesn't fit nicely into the standard algorithms in the Dragon Book).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is a bit better, as the "choice" is now it's own element (typeFacet), but cannot be used directly as it is abstract.

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="property">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element ref="typeFacet" />
        <xs:element name="os" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="condition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="typeFacet" abstract="true" />
  <xs:element name="val" type="xs:string"   substitutionGroup="typeFacet" />
  <xs:element name="perl" type="xs:string" substitutionGroup="typeFacet" />
  <xs:element name="shell" type="xs:string" substitutionGroup="typeFacet" />
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Yes, that's pretty well exactly what I meant but was too meetinged to actually do. Abstraction is definitely a good idea here too.

Comment: Great, I didn't know about substitution in XSD schema. This seems to be doing what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. This also works if val and perl are of different types.

Answer (score 7):

Based on newt's comment about using substitution groups for the choice (tested with xmllint):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="property">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element ref="val"/>
        <xs:element name="os" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="condition" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="val" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="perl" type="xs:string" substitutionGroup="val" />
  <xs:element name="shell" type="xs:string"  substitutionGroup="val" />
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know about substitution in XSD schema. This seems to be doing what I need. Thanks.