# Unordered list of elements including a choice between 1 element and a sequence of other 3 elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML that can be either like this:

```
<profile>
  <docname>Bla bla bla</docname>
  <author>Bubi</author>
  <doctype>INVOICE</doctype>
</profile>
```

or like this:

```
<profile>
  <author>Bubi</author>
  <docname>Bla bla bla</docname>
  <type1>3</type1>
  <type2>1</type2>
  <type3>0</type3>
</profile>
```

Elements can appear in any order. As you see it is required to have either `<doctype>` or `<type1>`, `<type2>` and `<type3>` tags.

I need an XSD for it. I tried with

```
<xs:element name="profile">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="author"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="docname"/>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element type="xs:string" name="doctype"/>
        <xs:sequence> <!--another little problem: I'd like to put a <xs:all> but is not allowed...-->
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="type1"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="type2"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="type3"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But `<xs:choice>` is not allowed inside an `<xs:all>` (**why is `<xs:all>` so mistreated???**). I found [this great related solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780817/xml-schema-why-cant-xsall-have-choice-children-and-how-can-this-be-bypass/781753#781753), but it works only if the choice is among single elements and not among groups of them.

Anyone knows a workaround? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here has to do with the unique particle attribution. If you have options, a Relax NG schema may help you instead. Otherwise, you'd have to complement a "weaker" XSD (do an xsd:all from all your six elements) with other mechanisms (a simple XSLT or handwritten code, etc.).