# XML Schema: Alternative elements in a list of many other elements

Tags: xsd

I am not very experienced with XSD, so bare with me.

I have a bunch of elements in any order. Some of these elements are optional others are required (*minOccurs="0"/maxOccurs="1"* or *minOccurs="1"/maxOccurs="1"*). The problem is, that either `Element3a` or `Element3b` exits in the list at any place but not both. Both of the elements `Element3a` and `Element3b` are marked as required (*minOccurs="1"/maxOccurs="1"*).

```
-Element1
-Element2
*Element3a
*Element3b
-Element4
-Element5
-Element6
-Element7
```

I tried `<xs:any>` as it allows elements in any order, but then the question is how can I define that either `Element3a` or `Element3b` is allowed in that `<xs:any>`. I tried to enclose `Element3a` and `Element3b` in a `<xs:choice>` but this is not allowed.

How can I accomplish a XSD that allows something like this?

I found this answer: [Unordered list of elements including a choice between 1 element and a sequence of other 3 elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827507/unordered-list-of-elements-including-a-choice-between-1-element-and-a-sequence-o)

I am not sure if this relates to my problem but somehow I guess that it might be.  I do not like to put this kind of validation in some code if it could be solved in XSD.

Answer (score 0):

Possible XSD 1.1 assertion:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="Element1"/>
        <xs:element name="Element2"/>
        <xs:element name="Element3a" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="Element3b" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>          
        <xs:element name="Element4"/>
        <xs:element name="Element5"/>
        <xs:element name="Element6"/>
        <xs:element name="Element7"/>
      </xs:all>
      <xs:assert test="Element3a and not(Element3b) or (not(Element3a) and Element3b)" id="Either_Element3a_or_Element3b"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```